# How to recover data from bit stream

Tags: string, matlab, binary

I have a txt file that has data:

```
123456789 abcef
```

Now I want to read it and recover it from bit stream. How to do it by matlab. I try to do it but to recovery that data from bit stream, it does not work 
This is my code

```
fid=fopen('test.txt','r');
sStream=fread(fid,'*char')' % to stream

%% convert to bit stream 0-1
sPacket=dec2bin(sStream,8);

%% store in vector Example s=[10000 1000 11101110 ...]
sPacket =  str2num(reshape(sPacket',[],8))';

%% Let recovery it to 123456789 abcef
%% Problem in here
out=bin2dec(sPacket);
```

Error using bin2dec (line 27)
Input must be a string.

Answer (score 1):

bin2dec accept string dataType as an argument

```
    dPacket = {}
    for idxsPacket = 1:size(sPacket,2)
      dPacket{idxsPacket} = char(bin2dec(num2str(sPacket(idxsPacket)))); 
    end
```

In this dPacket Stores Char value

Comment: Sir, It does not work. It is your output   Columns 1 through 12

    ''    '    'î'    'à'    ' '    '!'    'u'    'Ø'    ''    'C'    '«'    '²'

  Columns 13 through 20

    ' '    '$'    '÷'    'b'    ' '    'L'    'ª'    'à'

Comment: Well that's because your  sPacket =  str2num(reshape(sPacket',[],8))'; creation is not proper.

Comment: Need to look test.txt file. If you could provide sample of it, would be good. Won't understood why you want to convert to bin and then recover , file read operation can be easily done on string rather than converting to bin and dec back and forth.

Comment: you can make the test.txt and in the file you can put my data. The my problem that I am working in encoding and decoding. I run successfully for bit level. Now, i change it to packet level. Each packet has 8 bits. And I bitxor packet together. Because the code more complex, I only show sample case, in which does not have decode or encode step. Only encode to bit stream, and recover it

Comment: Problem is that sPacket =  str2num(reshape(sPacket',[],8))'; It tries to convert char to bit array. Example sPacket1=00011000...Do you have idea to resolve it?